# Select Group based on condition - Crystal Report

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I have a report where the data is displayed based on the value of a combobox, how do I display all the data if the combox is empty? I have done the below:

Under Select Expert -> Group

```
if {?@Div} <> " " then
    {SP;1.Col1} = {?@Div}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the {?@Div} var contains an empty string "if combobox is empty" the condition could look like this:

```
{SP;1.Col1} = {?@Div}
Or {?@Div} = ''
```

You might want to add an "All" group to the selection, then it would be something like:

```
{SP;1.Col1} = {?@Div}
Or {?@Div} = 'All'
```